# Using XPath to Extract and Use Data from a GET response

Tags: xml, rest, fitnesse

Here's the scenario...
I perform a GET to retrieve an XML.  I want to extract a value from the XML to use in a subsequent test.  For example, I do a GET to retrieve an Order XML.  I then want to extract the text of the ProposalNumber element and assign it to a variable using LET so that I may use it later in the test.  I downloaded a RestFixtureTest that does this exact scenario which works as expected and returns the text (using text()).  But when I try it with the system under test, the response is empty.  The only obvious difference I see is the Content-Type header.  The RestFixtureTest uses text/xml where my test uses application/xml.

Answer (score 0):

According to your web service, the Content-Type has to be updated before launching the web service using RestFixture of FITNESSE

For example, if your web service uses application/xml
Using SetHeaders and define Content-Type as application/xml

Then use let for parsing the XML response using below format,

|let |proposalnumber|body|//proposalnumber/text()|$proposalnumber=|

The value of proposalnumber tag will be stored in proposalnumber variable